# react-router-dom & nginx -> path /equipe/:id return index.html

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router-dom, nginx-config, react-dom

I use `react-router-dom` in my react application like this:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
// other code...
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="equipe" element={<Equipe/>}/>
            <Route path="equipe/:id" element={<Equipe/>}/>
            {/*other route...*/}
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I specify that by launching my application in development mode with `react-scripts start` I have no worries.

I build my project by running `react-scripts build`, which works.
I'm using the following `nginx` configuration:

```
server {
   server_name server_name_url;
   location / {
            root /path/to/folder/build;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   # other elements managed by Certbot
}
```

When I access `server_name_url/equipe` it works fine.

When I access `server_name_url/equipe/:id` (server_name_url/equipe/12345 for example) it returns me the index.html file instead of the `main.396fb688.js` file.

I understand why (related to try_files which can't find $uri and $uri/).
[image]

How can I modify the nginx configuration in order to access my `/equipe/:id` route please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have found a solution for your issue here. I had the same problem, it was because the environment variable `PUBLIC_URL` was **not** defined to `/`.
So I had to add to my .env file:

```
PUBLIC_URL=/
```

Try that one

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is that the requests to the `index.html` file are functioning properly, but you need to configure nginx to also redirect other requests to the `index.html` file too.

To resolve this, you need to update your `nginx` configuration to include a fallback route that directs all requests to the `index.html` file. This ensures that your application's routing system can handle the requests appropriately.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the same with your configuration